# postgres heroku, no response

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm just getting started with postgres, sorry for the very novice question.

I have the my heroku psql databade initiated and postgres client installed, but nothing really seems to responding and printing any response other than $ help. Is there anything I need to do after installing the postgres client?

I'm following this post: [heroku_postgres database create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775490/heroku-postgres-database-create-table)
And the command i'm trying is: psql -h XXXXXXX -U XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX

EDIT: heroku pg:psql

---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL (DATABASE_URL)
sh: psql: command not found

Comment: do you have psql installed?

Comment: `psql: command not found` means that, if you do actually have the postgres client installed, it's not found in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running `heroku pg:psql` ?

Comment: ---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL (DATABASE_URL)


What's the difference between maroon and the new one i created?